# Spring .properties file: get element as an Array

Tags: java, spring, placeholder, properties-file

I'm loading properties attributes from a `.properties` file using Spring as follows:

```
file: elements.properties
base.module.elementToSearch=1
base.module.elementToSearch=2
base.module.elementToSearch=3
base.module.elementToSearch=4
base.module.elementToSearch=5
base.module.elementToSearch=6
```

The spring xml file

```
file: myapplication.xml
<bean id="some"
      class="com.some.Class">
      <property name="property" value="#{base.module.elementToSearch}" />
</bean>
```

And my Class.java

```
file: Class.java
public void setProperty(final List<Integer> elements){
    this.elements = elements;
}
```

But when debugging, the parameter elements only get the last element into the list, so, there is a list of one element with value "6", instead of a list with 6 elements.

I tried other approaches, like adding in value only `#{base.module}` but then it finds no parameter in the properties file.

A workaround is to have in elements.properties file a list separated by commas, like:

```
base.module.elementToSearch=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

and use it as a String and parse it, but is there a better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify values in a properties file so they can be retrieved using ResourceBundle#getStringArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226050/how-do-i-specify-values-in-a-properties-file-so-they-can-be-retrieved-using-resou)

Comment: so I need to pass it as a comma separated string and parse in method.

Comment: Exactly, although there is some libs already doing that for you (apache commons) - http://commons.apache.org/configuration/howto_properties.html

Comment: Here's an answer that at least gives you a Set<String> result. Not quite a List<String>, but probably sufficient in many cases! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274362/reading-a-dynamic-property-list-into-a-spring-managed-bean

Comment: @Value("${key:one,two,three}") String[] arrayWithDefaults;

Answer (score 226, accepted):

If you define your array in properties file like:

```
base.module.elementToSearch=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

You can load such array in your Java class like this:

```
  @Value("${base.module.elementToSearch}")
  private String[] elementToSearch;
```

Comment: My elements contain comma. How do I escape separator? '\,' even '\\,' do not work.

Comment: You can try to get them as list of integer and then converts them
@Value( "${base.module.elementToSearch}")
private List<Integer> elementToSearch;

Comment: +1, just what I needed. Unfortunately reading comma-separated values into a `List<String>` in the same fashion doesn't seem to work (the list will have just one element).

Comment: I am failing to read them in to an array (String[]). Is this supposed to work?

Comment: I can confirm that using `String[]` as type works, where using `List<String>` does not work.

Comment: Under the hood this uses `org.springframework.util.StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(String)` to split the string, and this util method does not support any escapes, so if your values contain commas, you are out of luck and need to write your own converter.

Comment: If you want this to work with `List<String>` instead of `String[]`, you need to add at least a `<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">` to your `applicationContext.xml`. Otherwise the conversion service is not used but the default property editors, which do not support converting Strings to collections, only arrays: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config

Answer (score 47):

And incase you a different delimiter other than comma, you can use that as well.

```
@Value("#{'${my.config.values}'.split(',')}")
private String[] myValues;   // could also be a List<String>
```

and

in your application properties you could have

```
my.config.values=value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: this usage also works with other annotations, I used like @KafkaListener{topics= "#{'${ArrayProperty}'.split(',')}"} for spring kafka listener

Answer (score 35):

Here is an example of how you can do it in Spring 4.0+

## `application.properties` content:

```
some.key=yes,no,cancel
```

## Java Code:

```
@Autowire
private Environment env;

...

String[] springRocks = env.getProperty("some.key", String[].class);
```

Comment: this is what I want, but in env vars... I should be able to use SOME_KEY_0_=yes SOME_KEY_1=no, etc in env vars, but my getProperty is coming back null

Answer (score 12):

With a Spring Boot one can do the following:

## application.properties

```
values[0]=abc
values[1]=def
```

## Configuration class

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Configuration {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

}
```

This is needed, without this class or without the `values` in class it is not working.

## Spring Boot Application class

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);

    // notice #{} is used instead of ${}
    @Value("#{configuration.values}")
    List<String> values;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("values: {}", values);
    }

}
```

Comment: why `@Value("#{configuration.values}")` and not `@Value("#{values}")`, neither works for me btw...

Answer (score -2):

If you need to pass the asterisk symbol, you have to wrap it with quotes.

In my case, I need to configure cors for websockets. So, I decided to put cors urls into application.yml. For prod env I'll use specific urls, but for dev it's ok to use just *.

In yml file I have:

```
websocket:
  cors: "*"
```

In Config class I have:

```
@Value("${websocket.cors}")
private String[] cors;
```