# How to remove spaces in between quotes in spring bean property value

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean defined in my xml:

```
<bean class="myClass">
<property name="abc">
<value="${a}
${b}
${c}
" /></property>
</bean>
```

I don't want to put the values in one line. I want it to be in separate lines.

Property file:

```
a=abc'
b=def
c='xyz
```

The value in run time will be:

```
acb'    def    'xyz
```

How do I remove the white spaces from the value using springutils?

```
<bean class="myClass">
 <property name="abc">
 <bean class="org.springframework.util.StringUtils"
            factory-method="trimWhitespace">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">

<value="${a}
${b}
${c}
" /></bean></property>
</bean>
```

I'm looking for something like this - where I want to use trim function from java.lang.String:

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
<property name="randomNumber" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>

</bean>
```

Sorry for the mistake but its actually

```
acb '    def    ' xyz
```

There are white spaces after abc and before xyz
and I need these white spaces but not inside the quotes

Comment: Why is it so important that you have a value split up in such a way? Something along the lines `<value="#{org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(${a}${b}${c}}")/>` (whith new-lines between a/b/c could work.

Comment: Why is it so important that you have a value split up in such a way?
well, I have many keys like a,b,c to be appended for this property value and I want this to be dynamic as well. So, I want to change my property file instead of touching the xml and have enough readability as well

I'm looking at a similar thing but I want something like this -
    <value="${a}
    #{org.springframework.util.StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(${b})}
    ${c}"‌/>

Comment: is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Usually people inject lists when there are multiple properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552665/spring-boot-populate-list-collection-from-application-properties/37553434#37553434 and the method linked in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use line feed:

```
...
<value="${a}&#10;${b}&#10;${c}" />
...
```

Check all numeric code character entities: http://www.december.com/html/spec/codes.html

Comment: I tried this, and this prints out -
abc '  
def
  ' xyz
in multiple lines
here I also see whitecaps after abc' and before 'xyz