# How to convert these line to @Value Annotation format?

Tags: java, spring-boot

The code below, I need to convert them to @Value Annotations, But the difficult part of it is that I have to split the @Value after I split it once. As you can see I created a @Value annotation for APP_COMMAND and split it with delimiter '@!', and named it String[] appCommandArray; I want to be able to split appCommandArray again using the same idea but this time with delimiter of ',', But can you do @Value annotations on a variable? or does it has to come from a properties file?

**Value Annotations**

```
 @Value("#{'${APP_COMMAND}'.split('@!')}") 
 private String[] appCommandArray;      
 @Value("#{'${APP_THRESHOLD_VALUE_CRITICAL_HIGH}'.split('@!')}") 
 private String[] criticalThresholdArray;
```

**How to convert this**

```
    String[] commandArray=appCommandArray[j].split(",");
    String[] commandCriticalArray=criticalThresholdArray[j].split(",");
```

**Application Properties**

```
APP_COMMAND = test@!test@!test@!sleep@!sleep@!sleep@!foo,bar@!foo,bar@!foo,bar@!test@!test@!test@!sleep@!sleep@!foo,bar@!hello,world@!hello,world@!sleep
```

The script is splitting the values again.
I am not asking on how to display my @value annotations, I am asking on how can I split an @value annotation once it's already been split

Comment: Can you add your properties file, what you are trying to parse and retrieve ?

Comment: @javaguy I added a snippet of my code.

Comment: I think my code made it more confusing i'll delete the codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring .properties file: get element as an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212898/spring-properties-file-get-element-as-an-array)

Comment: @DavidSiro It's not the duplicate. I'm asking on how to split an annotation thats already been splitted.