# Is it possible to get an array of objects from Spring's application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

I know that I can create objects from `properties` file line properties.
I'd like to get a dynamic array of objects, something like this.

**application.properties**

```
heroes.hero1=1,superman,kent
heroes.hero2=2,batman,wayne
```

Let's say that sometime somebody will add another hero to the file. Is it possible for spring to automatically understand additions to array of heroes? Is there a solution to this? Or is it just easier to read and construct such objects from txt files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring .properties file: get element as an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212898/spring-properties-file-get-element-as-an-array)

Comment: @chsdk it is not the same question. They are getting array from property value I want an array of properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually implement this using Spring Boot Core Functionality:

Create for instance a new Java Class (with use of Lombok for Getters/ Setters now)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "heroes")
@Getter
@Setter
public class HeroesProperties {

    private Map<String, List<String>> heroesMapping;

}
```

And in your application.properties you can add dynamically more heroes in your way.

E.g.

- `heroes.hero1=1,superman,kent`
- `heroes.hero2=2,xx,aa`
- `heroes.hero3=3,yy,bb`
- `heroes.heroN=4,zz,cc`

Answer (score 1):

inject `Environment` and call `getProperty` :

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;   

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public String[] getHero() {
   return env.getProperty("heroes",String[].class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use following code for injecting these properties:

```
@Value("${heroes.hero1}")
private String[] heroes1;

@Value("${heroes.hero2}")
private String[] heroes2;
```

Comment: I understand this. But what about the second part asked: `Let's say that sometime somebody will add another hero to the file. Is it possible for spring to automatically understand additions to array of heroes?`

Comment: No it is not possible. This are properties and they are loaded at boot time. Yo will have to handle this case yourself.

Comment: It want be recognised without app restart.

Comment: true, but it's ok. as long as a semi pro user can change the properties and restart the app - i'm fine with it. he doesn't need to go into the code much.

Comment: Yes, I agree on that.