# Reading multiple entity scan packages in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have Spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"${scan.packages}"})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

While reading  multiple entity scan packages from one property separated by comma like below?

> scan.packages=com.mycompany.model.package1 ,
>   com.mycompany.model.package2

I got this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
>   com.mycompany.model.package2.Myclass

Comment: Remove the `{}` from the entity scan and Spring then might try to resolve them to an array. If that doesn't work you might want to use a SpEL expression to do that for you. Although you might want to reconsider if this is really what you want/need.

Answer (score 18):

You can scan multiple Entity like this

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"scan.packages1","scan.packages2"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i need to read them as one property separated by comma

Comment: what you mean by one property separated by comma

Comment: you want to import scan package from any property file ?

Comment: No I have one property like   property=package1, package2       I need to read only this property to scan the two packages

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```java
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"#{'${scan.packages}'.split(',')}"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bunyamin , unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @Elsayed [the original response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212898/spring-properties-file-get-element-as-an-array) for more context. Even though I couldn't manage to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [EntityScan annotation javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html) there are three ways to define the packages where to scan for entities:

1. [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#value--), alias for [basePackages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#basePackages--):  `@EntityScan( {"scan.packages1","scan.packages2"})`
2. [basePackages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#basePackages--), alias for [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#value--): `@EntityScan(basePackages= {"scan.packages1","scan.packages2"})`.
3. [basePackagesClasses](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#basePackageClasses--), the type safe version: `@EntityScan(basePackages=E.class}`.Where **E** was a marker interface just to underline the Entities. Please see the code bellow. It could also be an annotation.

   ```
   interface E {
   }

   @Entity
   public class Glass implements E {
   // Typical code to be added here
   }
   ```

Or as an annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@interface E {
}

@Entity
@E
public class Glass implements E {
   // Typical code to be added here
}
```

From my perspective I would choose either using directly [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#value--) or [basePackageClasses](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#basePackageClasses--). If I can something easier to read I would do that, and I think that is what [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#value--) does, while the [basePackageClasses](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html#basePackageClasses--) introduces the added benefit of type safety and I can see multiple reasons to go for that. It all depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and posted an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25415#event-4375228359) on the Spring Boot issue tracker about it.

The answer was that

> ... As shown by [#25436](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25436), `@EntityScan` did support property solution in 2.3 so, if we decide to reinstate support, we might want to consider how to handle multi-value properties.

So it appears some Spring Boot version did support it, but then the support was dropped again... for more info, check the Spring Boot issue linked in the quote.

Answer (score -3):

try this :

```
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"${scan.packages1","scan.packages2}"})
```

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it