# spring dynamic domain in HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to spring and its bean injection framework and I need advice on understanding how to utilize them. Currently I have the following,

```
<beans>   
    <bean id="citationService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/PPDFWeb/hello.htm"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="test_client.HelloService"/>
        <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.remoting.httpinvoker.AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor">
             </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now i need the domain name of the service url to be dynamic so I can set it somewhere programmatically in my code. Is there some way to leave the bean intact in the xml and change the serviceUrl of the bean?

Answer (score 0):

Just mark it like:

```
<property name="serviceUrl" value="{serviceURL}"/>
```

Edit:

There are just too many solutions available on SO, I didn't do a good search earlier:

1. [reading a dynamic property list into a spring managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274362/reading-a-dynamic-property-list-into-a-spring-managed-bean)
2. [HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean-set-url-dynamically](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?25269-HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean-set-url-dynamically)

Comment: Noob question 2 how do I set the curly braces

Comment: updated my post, the second link is exactly what you are looking for