# Reading values from a property file into a Map<PropertyName, ListOfValues>?

Tags: java, spring, list, dictionary, properties

I have the following property file

- MyCat.MyVal1=a,b,c,d,e
- MyCat.MyVal2=z,d,e
- MyCat.MyVal3=a,b

And need to construct a map with key being the key of the property file and the value a list Strings being the property value e.g. MyMap(String,List)

Example having a map with

- Key = MyCat.MyVal1 value List a,b,c,d,e
- Key = MyCat.MyVal2 value List z,d,e

Now I know you can read a specific value from a property file using Spring into a list

```
@Component
class MyClass {
@Value("${my.property.name}")
private String[] myValues;
}
```

And ultimately the only way I can figure out how to do this is to write a custom class to read all the properties line by line and take the value of the property and split them and create a list from based on that and construct a map.

Just wanted to ask if there is an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change properties format and use a great library - [Yaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) - that might be handy in many similar tasks .
It looks like..

> JYaml makes it easy to take advantage of the flexibility of Yaml. By default, JYaml converts a sequence to java.util.ArrayList and a mapping to java.util.HashMap. However, this behavior can be overriden by either tagging or type inference, which is what allows for a mapping to be transformed to a JavaBean, or a sequence to be transformed to an array or a different kind of Collection.
>
> To write a Java object to a file in Yaml format, all you have to do is

`Yaml.dump(object, new File("object.yml"));`

Conversely, to load a Yaml file into Java land

`Object object = Yaml.load(new File("object.yml"));`

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to read values from property file.

So, your code probably looks similar to,

```
 private Properties loadProperty(String propertiesFilePath)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
  {
    Properties metaData = new Properties();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(propertiesFilePath));
    metaData.load(fis);

    fis.close();
    return (metaData);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, I am happy with reading the property files and create the Map<String, List<String>) structure myself. I just wanted to know if there is not another way to do this automatically. Don't want to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: @Chrispie: Do you want something like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760200/reading-a-dynamic-property-map-into-spring-managed-bean?rq=1