# How do i read the application.properties in spring?

Tags: spring, javabeans

question is related to Spring. I have `application.properties` file in my project. I want these values to be used in my service class. Can i get these properties values as a bean in my service class?

```
class MyServiceClass{
    @Autowired
    Properties myproperty;

    // ....
}
```

i want to be able to use myproperty. What config changes should be made to wire the `application.properties` with my service class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading a dynamic property list into a spring managed bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274362/reading-a-dynamic-property-list-into-a-spring-managed-bean)

Comment: That is not a duplicate of this one. But there should be one, seems like a common thing to want to do. +1 since I cannot find a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject them into your beans:

```
 @Value("${name}")
 private String someConfiguration;
```

Comment: I want the complete key - value pairs of application.properties as a bean.

Comment: say, Properties myproperty should be autowired.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the question. I guess you want to access both the key and values from your props file? If so, perhaps this will help:

```
<bean id="mapProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myMap" class="com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap" factory-method="copyOf">
    <constructor-arg ref="mapProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Now you can access myMap in your beans as you would normally:

```
@Autowired
private ImmutableMap<String, String> myMap;
```

This example uses a guava ImmutableMap, but you can probably use HashMap or whatever.